# Input que depende del select LARAVEL

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy intentando sacar datos de un `select`.

Por ejemplo imaginemos que tengo un `select` que tiene lo clásico de los productos, como nombre, descripción, precio, etc....

El caso es que consigo ese `select` con el `pluck` pero como podría hacer que al seleccionar algo, me mande a un `input` por ejemplo el precio o la descripción?

Esto es lo que llevo por ahora:

**Mi Controlador:**

```
public function lista(){

  $productos = Productos::pluck('Codigo','Descripcion','PVP','id')->prepend('selecciona'); 
  return view ('Productos.NuevoProducto2',compact('productos'));

}
```

**Mi vista:**

```
@extends('admin.plantilla')

@section('content')

@include('admin.partial.error')

{!! Form::select('producto',$productos,null,['id'=>'producto', 'data-live-search'=>'true']) !!}

@endsection

@section('javascript')

@stop
```

**Y mi ruta:**

```
Route::get('/probando','ProductosController@lista')->name('listaProductos');
```

Aún no he incluido los `input`,ya que no sé como puedo conseguir extraer esos datos.

alguna ayuda?